# Do I always need to peel the avocado or I can just chop it?

Tags: avocados

Do I always need to peel the avocado, or can I just chop it?

Comment: In case you're not aware: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/1913/6317 explains the easiest way to get avocado chunks. Peeling then slicing is not recommended;  using that technique you can slice the avocado into chunks then invert the peel to release them. Much easier.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I certainly wouldn't want to be chewing through avocado skin.  Unless you plan on throwing it in a blender and liquifying it, it'd be pretty nasty.

Comment: +1. Just out of curiosity, I just tasted some avocado skin. It is bitter and nasty. No redeeming qualities what so ever.

Comment: The skin has a toxin in it, blending it for consumption would perhaps be a very bad idea.

Answer (score 10):

Some varieties of avocado do have edible skin (e.g., "[topa topa](http://www.crfg.org/pubs/ff/avocado.html)"); however, such varieties are rarely cultivated since they are extremely perishable. The vast majority of avocados that are marketed in the USA have skins that are too thick for consumption. If you are in doubt, just cut off a small piece of the skin and chew it. If it feels like you're chewing leather, chances are you'll have to peel it. Eating the skin is harmless [unless you're a domestic animal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persin).

Answer (score 3):

Sure you can. My favorite brunch is cutting an avocado in 1/2, scoop out a little extra then add an egg in each 1/2 and bake till desired done-ness which is about 20 min for a done yolk. This softens the skin of the Avocado and makes it quite pleasant to eat. Add your own twist but I suggest you top with cheese and serve with a hash brown or grits. Nom, nom, nom!

Comment: So you can skip peeling it if you're going to bake it? In my experience thicker avocado skin is still pretty tough to eat at that point, and that does pretty drastically alter the texture of the avocado - not necessarily the most useful thing for someone who wants fresh avocado.

Comment: Wow, interesting. I've never heard of a preparation like this.