# What method can be used to peel an Avocado without damaging it?

Tags: equipment, utensils, peeling

This is a problem I really have each time I want to peel them. Over the years I used forks, spoons and knifes but always the Avocado gets damaged as it is mushy, pulpy when I peel it and gets a mess. Is there any method than can I use to properly peel it or perhaps a tool developed for this purpose?. If there is a video or picture that can accompany the answer that would help me a lot.

Comment: Related: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/1911/how-can-i-remove-the-peel-and-pit-of-an-avocado-without-the-whole-thing-turning?rq=1

Comment: @Stephie I didn't included information about ripe but I usually cut them when they're okay to be eaten. Cutting in half is acceptable but cutting it in blocks not.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, the most important part of peeling an avocado without damaging it is to first select an avocado that is perfectly ripe.  A perfectly ripe avocado will yield to gentle pressure in the palm of your hand.  Once you've selected appropriately, halve it lengthwise and whack the pit with a heavy, sharp knife and lift it out.  Then use your fingers to gently remove the peel. If the peel does not separate cleanly, try it again with a less ripe avocado.

Comment: If his intent is to peel it WHOLE, then ripeness will be the problem rather than the solution...

Comment: @rackandboneman I usually try to peel them by cutting them in half and removing the seed with a spoon but this method always gives me some troubles.

Comment: @rackandboneman no where in his question does he say he wants to peel it WHOLE.  I have never seen an avocado served whole, with the pit still inside, so peeling it that way doesn't even make any sense.